# Applying code that alters sharpness of a png image file to an entire file of images?

Tags: python, image, neural-network

So I have this code that changes the sharpness of an image but I would like to use it on a file of 5000 ish images. How to do so in python? And if I run this code on my file, do I just use my neural network code with the name of the altered images as the input?

```
from PIL import ImageEnhance

enhancer = ImageEnhance.Sharpness(image)

for i in range(8):
    factor = i / 4.0
    enhancer.enhance(factor).show("Sharpness %f" % factor)
```

Comment: where is the neural network part in your code?

Comment: What file can contain 5,000 images? Is it a TIFF file?

Comment: it's afterwards. I'm mainly asking about how to make this image editing code apply to an entire file of images

Comment: It's a dataset file I got from kaggle with thousands of bee images haha